# Cannot connect to dockerhost from docker image

Tags: docker, docker-multi-stage-build, docker-in-docker

I am trying to use docker(dind) image for building an image. When I run ***docker info*** in the DockerFile, it complains dockerhost cannot be found. Is there any way when building a Docker image, can we use docker host in the build step ?

Comment: Can you please provide more details like what exactly you are trying to achive?

Comment: Trying to kick start docker when building the image via Dockerfile. `FROM docker:dind
RUN apk update
RUN apk add --no-cache openjdk8 git maven
COPY daemon.json  /etc/docker/
COPY config.json  /.docker/ RUN docker info
COPY settings.xml /usr/share/java/maven-3/conf/settings.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is an effective way to run docker in DIND when building image via dockerfile. I ran a container version of DIND image and added all the config stuff and committed that to an image which solved the problem of me using dind